# Invalid characters and modules when translating a node.js app from javascript to coffee script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, coffeescript

So basically I'm trying to follow the tutorial listed [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular#frontend-application-with-angular), except using coffee script instead of javascript. I'm getting two errors on the website,
 1. A syntax error regarding the '#' character in the first line of core.coffee (# public/core.coffee) 
 2. an error that says no module: scotchTodo.
 
On the actual page, instead of showing the number of todos and each todo, it says 
**`{{ todos.length }} and {{ todo.text }}`**.

Here's my **core.coffee:**

```
# public/core.coffee

scotchTodo = angular.module 'scotchTodo', []

mainController = ($scope, $http) ->
    $scope.formData = {}

    # when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
    $http.get '/api/todos'
        .success((data) ->
            $scope.todos = data
            console.log data
        ).error((data) ->
            console.log 'Error: ' + data
        )

    # when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    $scope.createTodo = ->
        $http.post '/api/todos', $scope.formData
            .success((data) ->
                $scope.formData = {} # clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                $scope.todos = data
                console.log data
            ).error((data) ->
                console.log 'Error: ' + data
            )

    # delete a todo after checking it
    $scope.deleteTodo = (id) ->
        $http.delete '/api/todos/' + id
            .success((data) ->
                $scope.todos = data
                console.log data
            ).error((data) ->
                console.log 'Error: ' + data
            )
```

Here's my **index.html:**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>

<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="scotchTodo">
<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

    <title>Todo App</title>

    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- load bootstrap -->
    <style>
        html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
        body                    { padding-top:50px; }
        #todo-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }
    </style>

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="core.coffee"></script>

</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL TODOS -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>I'm a Todo-aholic <span class="label label-info">{{ todos.length }}</span></h1>
        </div>

        <!-- TODO LIST -->
        <div id="todo-list" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">

                <!-- LOOP OVER THE TODOS IN $scope.todos -->
                <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteTodo(todo._id)"> {{ todo.text }}
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- FORM TO CREATE TODOS -->
        <div id="todo-form" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <!-- BIND THIS VALUE TO formData.text IN ANGULAR -->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg text-center" placeholder="I want to buy a puppy that will love me forever" ng-model="formData.text">
                    </div>

                    <!-- createToDo() WILL CREATE NEW TODOS -->
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createTodo()">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else from me, really trying to understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact syntax error? Is something trying to interpret your CoffeeScript as JavaScript perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use CoffeeScript in the browser:

```
<script src="core.coffee"></script>
```

You need to either compile it first, or ad the compiler to your browser code so it can be compiled on the fly. The latter is generally not a good idea, so you should add a build step that uses the CoffeeScript compiler to turn your `core.coffee` into `core.js`, then include that script in your `index.html`.

From the terminal that would look something like `coffee -c core.coffee`, but there are more options as can be seen [here](http://coffeescript.org/#usage).